# ¿Que tan correcto es actualizar un registro de una tabla en mysql , utilizando un campo que no sea la llave primaria? ¿Afecta al rendimeinto de mi BD?

Tags: mysql

Quiero actualizar un registro en utilizando un campo que no es la llave primaria, mitabla tiene los campos:(id, nombre, direccion, email) quiero actualizar un registro utilizando el campo email. mi duda es: ¿tendre problemas al tener miles de registro y hacer una consulta de ese tipo en mi base de datos?

Comment: Depende de lo que conlleve... Por ejemplo. Si una persona crea 2 cuentas en la misma web, y en ambas cuentas usa el mismo correo... Tu al hacer un UPDATE sobre el correo, estarás actualizando 2 registros, en vez de actualizar 1 como debiese ser.

Comment: El tema de una clave primaria, es que es única, y solo para esa fila del registro. Lo que la vuelve en el identificador del mismo, por eso muchas veces se usa ID como clave primaria. https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clave_primaria

Comment: Es una mala práctica que conlleva a que tu software no sea de calidad.

Comment: validare el registro de correo para que sea único. ¿hacer este tipo de consultas (no utilizando la llave primaria como referencia), afectaría el rendimiento?

Comment: Considera que la pregunta parece basada en opiniones y eso motivará su cierre

Comment: @Jbarrera No entiendo, por que entonces no usas la clave primaria como cualquiera lo haría ?? Estás evitándola, y luego dando una vuelta alrededor de ella... y haciendo otra clave unica que hará lo mismo que la primera.

Comment: @Excorpion Puede ser que el dato del que disponga en ese instante sea el email y prefiera usar un `AUTO_INCREMENT` para las `FK`. Además, nada impide disponer de varias claves candidatas a principal en una tabla

Comment: @DavidJP, pero la pregunta era para él.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Únicamente te arriesgas a que, si hay duplicados en ese campo, se te actualicen todos los registros en los que el dato de ese campo coincida.

Si ese riesgo es asumible o no, dependerá de opiniones.

Si quieres evitar duplicados en ese campo, simplemente tienes que rechazar nulos y crear una clave única así:

```
ALTER TABLE tabla MODIFY email VARCHAR(127) NOT NULL;

ALTER TABLE tabla ADD UNIQUE(email);
```

Desde ese momento será tan fiable y eficiente como una `PRIMARY KEY`